# Паттерн в DecimalFormatSymbols

Tags: java

Используя такой формат

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
new DecimalFormat("#.000000", dfs).format(new BigDecimal("1.23"))
```

Для чисел `1.23`, `2.33` будет возвращаться нормальное число `1.230000`, `2.330000`.

Но если применить число `0.01` в итоге будет `.010000`.

Необходимо чтобы возвращало нормальное число с `6` знаками после точки. Какой паттерн для этого использовать подскажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.000000", dfs).format(new BigDecimal("0.23"));
```